# How do I determine which Windows balloon tooltip was clicked?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I have a C# application which displays several different kinds of balloon notifications in Windows using [`NotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160065(v=vs.110).aspx). I want to be able to associate an action with each balloon tip if the user clicks it. However, [`NotifyIcon.BalloonTipClicked`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.balloontipclicked(v=vs.110).aspx) does not appear to offer any indication of which balloon the user actually clicked. How can I determine which balloon tip the user interacted with?

Here is a brief sample demonstrating the problem:

```
var notifyIcon = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon
{
    Text = "testing notifications",
    Icon = System.Drawing.SystemIcons.Application,
    Visible = true
};

notifyIcon.BalloonTipClicked += (sender, args) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"User clicked a balloon, but which one? sender: {sender}, args: {args}");
};

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(30000, $"title {i}", $"text {i}", System.Windows.Forms.ToolTipIcon.Info);
}
```

Comment: Don't use the same NotifyIcon for everything.  Try creating a specific NotifyIcon for each "different kind" as you put it.

Comment: That is indeed a workaround, but it has the drawback of adding a new icon to the notification tray for each `NotifyIcon`. I'm hoping there's something a little cleaner than that.